# Built in Constructor functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, constructor

When I do:

```
var person = new Object();  
person.name = "alex";
console.log(person)
```

output is:

```
Object { name="alex"}
```

However, say I drop the "new" word and do:

```
var person = Object();  
person.name = "alex";
console.log(person)
```

Output is also:

```
Object { name="alex"}
```

Why?

Comment: The `Object()` constructor behaves identically with and without the `new` keyword. That's just how it works.

Comment: Note that `Array()` and `new Array()` work the same way too.

Answer (score 4):

Because some built-in functions are just defined to act this way. For example see [ES5 15.2.1.1 for `Object`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.1.1):

> #### [15.2.1.1 Object ( [ value ] )](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.1.1)
>
> When the `Object` function is called with no arguments or with one argument *value*, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. If *value* is `null`, `undefined` or not supplied, create and return a new Object object exactly as if the standard built-in Object constructor had been called with the same arguments ([15.2.2.1](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.2.1)).
> 2. Return `ToObject(value)`.

They test whether they have been called with `new` or not and if not act like they'd have been called with `new`.

Not all constructors work like this. For example `Date` will return a string when called without `new`.

---

You can implement this yourself:

```
function Foo() {
    if(!(this instanceof Foo)) {
        return new Foo();
    }
    // do other init stuff
}
```

`Foo()` and `new Foo()` will act the same way (it gets more tricky with variable arguments though).

Answer (score 0):

Since your example is an Object type of built-in function, as it is answered above it is the same for this type, it does not work the same way for most of the other built-in functions such as Number(). You should be very careful when invoking them with the 'new' keyword or not. Because by default the 'new' keyword with a function constructor returns an object, not a primitive type directly. So you can not, for example, check strict equality on two variables that one of them is declared and assigned using `new Number()` , and the other is with `Number()`

An example would be:

```
var num1 = Number(26); 
var num2 = new Number(26);

num1 == num2; // returns true

num1 === num2; // returns false
```

You may checkout the difference at the console log:

```
console.log(num1);
> 26

console.log(num2);
> Number {26}
>     __proto__: Number
>     [[PrimitiveValue]]: 26
```